# EXSLT function (in lxml) returns no result

Tags: xslt, lxml, exslt

I'm trying to write a EXSLT function, but for some reason it doesn't seem to return the result. The function is supposed to look up a node in another document:

```
<func:function name="toc:element">
  <xsl:param name="id" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$toc">
    <func:result select="key('id', $id)" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</func:function>
```

With `xsl:message` I can see that it indeed receives a valid `$id` and the `key()` returns a single node; but when I call it from another template, it seems to produce no result.

Environment: `libxml2`/`libxslt`, not sure how to check the version; I'm using them from `lxml` v3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: if I add an intermediate variable, everything works.

```
<func:function name="toc:element">
  <xsl:param name="id" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$toc">
    <xsl:variable name="result" select="key('id', $id)" />
    <func:result select="$result" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</func:function>
```

Apparently, the function result uses the original context to evaluate.

Comment: Since this looks rather like a bug, it would be helpful for future readers to document which XSLT processor you are using. In fact, when you are using extensions like this, this is essential.

Comment: @MichaelKay Added a note about environment; it's `libxslt`, I'm using it from Python via `lxml` 3.2.3.

Comment: I don't know anything about libxslt's implementation of func:function, but now we have this information, someone else might be able to help.